# Unique elements of two vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors and I need to find out the unique elements in both, together.

I tried doing `length(summary(merge(v1, v2)))` but summary aggregates a bunch of my dataset because there is only one of those entries, so I get an incorrect length.

E.g.:

```
list_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,1,2,3)

list_2 <- c(2,3,4,5,10,11,10)
```

and the outcome should be

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11
```

P.S. bonus points if you can return all the unique elements in a vector... :-)

Comment: I don't understand your "bonus points" question.

Comment: For getting them sorted I used the below answer plus: `d <- union(v1, v2); d<-d[order(nchar(d))]`

Comment: Can you clarify your data structure? @DatamineR has created lists while your original question indicated vectors (even though you used the terminology "list").

Comment: It's a vector sorry about that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `union`:

```
> union(v1, v2)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 10 11
```

Answer (score 5):

here is my solution.

```
p1 <- c(1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
p2 <- c(3, 4, 1, 6, 90, 10, 32)
unique(c(p1, p2))
```

Comment: Not a bad idea either!

Comment: This solutions still works when introducing a third of fourth vector! The `union()` example can only handle two vectors at a time... Thanks for the share, this is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use unlist with union

```
    unlist(union(a,b))
```

Comment: Why do you need `unlist`?

Comment: earlier the list was created with list(). The edited way will not need unlist.

Comment: The original (unedited) question showed the data as vectors. The "edited way" that you refer to was posted earlier than your answer by at least 5 minutes and almost 20 minutes after the OP already posted a comment showing what they had tried (thus reinforcing the idea that they were vectors). `unlist` works on vectors too, but this doesn't seem to add much that isn't already there in the answers.... Just my 2 cents....

Comment: I see ..thank you for pointing out. I had just taken the un-edited question and posted the answer ..didn't notice the qs being edited before posting the solution.